# How To: Non-Facebook-Users post to Facebook page wall

Tags: php, facebook, access-token, facebook-wall

I am thinking of a scenario and I need your opinions whether this is even possible.

I have a normal website, on this website I have a form and by sending the form it should be also sent to one specific facebook page. As a normal page status update. Now I do not want to force my users to register to facebook in order to send the form.

By reading some articles here and the facebook API I think this could be possible, but I have one problem I can not solve:

1. Facebook app creation
2. Getting user token of the admin
3. Getting the page access token to post on the page wall

These points (1-3) should work fine, BUT here is my problem:

If I am right the token expires after some time - How is it possible to get a token which does not expire? Or are there some other ways to solve this problem?

This is the working code to post on the facebook page:

```
$attachment = array(
'access_token' => 'BACyul4fRfyEmI3xwMDs..........................',
'message'=> "Hello Test"
);
$result = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
```

Answer (score 1):

> How is it possible to get a token which does not expire? Or are there
>   some other ways to solve this problem?

It is not possible to get a token that does not expire, but they can be extended. Read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/) for more information. But the best practice is see if they are already logged in with the SDK, if they're not then redirect them to login. It's that simple.

You do not need to add an `access_token` in the attachment, the facebook SDK will handle that for you. So this is fine:

```
$attachment = array(
'message'=> "Hello Test"
);
$result = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
```

More parameters are available in this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

Comment: so my users need to have a facebook account? or me as the admin need to extend the token? there is no other way?

Comment: when I do not add the `access_token` as you said I get this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action`

Comment: Hm, then I guess add it. And yes, In order to post anything to your wall on behalf of a user, the user must have a facebook account.